# using postgesql DB with spring Boot application. app using r2dbc config to connect with DB. want to create jdbc config with r2dbc to connect same DB

Tags: jdbc, datasource, r2dbc-postgresql

r2dbc:
url: r2dbc:postgresql://${DB.URL:}/${DB.NAME:}?currentSchema=${DB.SCHEMA.NAME:}
username: ${DB.USERNAME:}
password: ${DB.PASSWORD:}
pool:
enabled: true
initial-size: 5
max-size: 100

jdbc-datasource:
url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB.URL:}/${DB.NAME:}?currentSchema=${DB.SCHEMA.NAME:dev}
driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
username: ${DB.USERNAME:}
password: ${DB.PASSWORD:}

```
@Bean(name="quartzDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.jdbc-datasource")
public DataSource createQuartzDB(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .type(HikariDataSource.class)
            .url("url")
            .username("username")
           .password("password")
            .driverClassName("driver-class-name")
            .build();
}
```

I tried to create jdbc DataSource to connect database in blocking way as quartz doesn't support the r2dbc. now we are using r2dbc to connect with Postgesql DB. I want JDBC along with r2DBC./ when I run the application I got error. like:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/e314/zsegment/api/configuration/QuartzDatSourceConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'createQuartzDB' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class driver-class-name in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:415)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
at com.e314.zsegment.api.ZSegmentApiApplication.main(ZSegmentApiApplication.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/e314/zsegment/api/configuration/QuartzDatSourceConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'createQuartzDB' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class driver-class-name in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'createQuartzDB' threw exception with message: Failed to load driver class driver-class-name in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class driver-class-name in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:488)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperty.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:479)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:373)
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:183)
at com.e314.zsegment.api.configuration.QuartzDatSourceConfig.createQuartzDB(QuartzDatSourceConfig.java:26)
at com.e314.zsegment.api.configuration.QuartzDatSourceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$createQuartzDB$0()
at com.e314.zsegment.api.configuration.QuartzDatSourceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
at com.e314.zsegment.api.configuration.QuartzDatSourceConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createQuartzDB()
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
... 43 common frames omitted